# A closed form for the sum $\sum_{s=0}^{n-1} e^{\frac{s(s+1)}{2}i\theta}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, fractals

What I'm really looking for is a good way to calculate the sum in parallel across many $n$ for a given real valued $\theta$.  Why?  Consider the Logo program:

```
to doit :r :dr
  forward 10
  right :r
  doit :r :r + :dr
end
```

It tends to draw [cute, curly paths](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/605658/).  I'd like to be able to draw these quickly (as a shader) in order make animations from varying `:r` and `:dr`.

The sum $\sum_{s=0}^{n-1} e^{\frac{s(s+1)}{2}i\theta}$ basically tells you the location of the turtle at the $n$th step where $\theta$ = `:dr` and the coordinates are rotated and reflected.

For example, with $\theta = \pi/2$ we get a very small zigzag figure as we increase $n$:

$$
\begin{matrix}
n & \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} e^{\frac{s(s+1)}{2}i\theta} \\
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 + i \\
3 & 1 \\
4 & 0 \\
5 & -1 \\
6 & -1 - i \\
7 & -1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: What kind of $n$ are we talking about here?

Comment: I can't help but notice that this looks like the DFT of $e^{-\frac{s+1}{2}}$ for an DFT of length $n$, with $s$ as the time domain variable and $\theta$ as the frequency domain variable.

Comment: You might find this paper interesting: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pcma/1416406253

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum#Parallel_algorithm may help with your initial goal of calculating many related sums.

Comment: Any responses to the comments, wl?

Comment: The paper is on topic, dense, will take a while to digest.  Doesn't answer the question but brings up many more good ones.